# Paginação não funciona

Tags: php, sql, paginação

Acabei de fazer o campo de pesquisa e a paginação do meu projeto, no entanto tenho 17 registos já adicionados mas apenas apresenta 8 registos
Fiz o código com o objetivo de apresentar 15 registos por página, ou seja, na segunda página deveria aparecer os 2 registos que faltam. No entanto avisa que existem 2 páginas, mas a segunda página se encontra vazia.

```html
<?php
 $sql="select * from Terceiros";
 $res=$lig->query($sql);
?>

 <head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb18030">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

   <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; width=device-width;">

             <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
           <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
 </head>

<?php
//paginação
 $tp=15;
 if (isset($_REQUEST['pesquisa'])) 
  $pesq='%'.$_REQUEST['pesquisa'].'%'; 
 
 if (isset($_REQUEST['pag'])) 
  $np=$_REQUEST['pag']; 
 else 
  $np=1;
 $ini=($np-1)*$tp;
 
 $sql="select * from Terceiros";
 if(isset($pesq))
  $sql.=" where Nome like '$pesq'";
 $res=$lig->query($sql);
 $nr=$res->num_rows;
 $qp=$nr/$tp+1;
//Fim paginação 
  
 $sql="SELECT Terceiros.*, Email, Telefone, Telemovel, TipoC, Morada, Localidade, CodPostal FROM ((Terceiros INNER JOIN  Contactos_Terceiro on  Terceiros.CodCon = Contactos_Terceiro.CodCon ) INNER JOIN Morada_Terceiro on Terceiros.Numero = Morada_Terceiro.Numero )";
 if(isset($pesq))
 $sql.=" where Nome like '$pesq'";
 $sql.=" limit $ini, $tp";
 $res=$lig->query($sql);
?>

  

<div class="container">
  <h1 align="center">Listar Terceiros</h1> <br><br>      
  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
 <tr>
      <tr>  
   <th colspan=3>
   <form method="POST" class="form-inline" action="index.php?cmd=lister">
     <div class="form-group">
    <label for="Pesquisa" >Pesquisar Terceiros: </label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="pesquisa" name="pesquisa">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Pesquisar</button>
     </div>
   </form>
   </th>
  </tr> 
       <th>Numero</th>
        <th>Cliente</th>
  <th>Fornecedor</th>
  <th>NIF</th>
  <th>Nome</th>
  <th>IdSiliamb</th>
  <th>Tipo</th>
  <th></th>
  <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    
    
<?php    
//$sql= "SELECT Terceiros.*, Email, Telefone, Telemovel, TipoC, Morada, Localidade, CodPostal from Terceiros, Contactos_Terceiro, Morada_Terceiro ";
//$sql.="WHERE Contactos_Terceiro.CodCon = Terceiros.CodCon and Morada_Terceiro.Numero = Terceiros.Numero  ";
//$res=$lig->query($sql);          
while ($lin=$res->fetch_array()){ ?>   
      <tr>
        <td><?php echo$lin[Numero]; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo$lin[Cliente]; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo$lin[Fornecedor]; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo$lin[NIF]; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo$lin[Nome]; ?></td>
  <td><?php echo$lin[Idsiliamb]; ?></td> 
  <td><?php echo$lin[Tipo]; ?></td>

        <td><a href=index.php?cmd=editer&Numero=<?php echo$lin[Numero];?> title="Editar"><img src='Imagens/edit.png' width="20" height = "20" ></a></td>
  <td><a href=index.php?cmd=delter&Numero=<?php echo$lin[Numero];?> title="Apagar" onclick="return confirm('Tem a certeza que deseja apagar este registo?');" ><img src='Imagens/delete.png' width="20" height = "20" ></a></td>
  <td><td><button data-toggle = "modal" data-target = "#<?php echo$lin[Numero];?>" title="Visualizar" class="btn btn-default openBtn"><img src='Imagens/eye.png' width="20" height = "20" ><button></td></td>
      </tr> 
   
<?php  } ?>

    </tbody>
  </table>  
  
<?php //Paginação 
 for ($i=1; $i<$qp; $i++)
  echo "<a href=index.php?cmd=lister&pag=$i>&nbsp$i&nbsp</a>";
?>
        
</div>
```

Comment: Printa o `$sql` da ultima consulta para ver como estão os valores da paginação

Comment: Apareceu o seguinte: " 

SELECT Terceiros.*, Email, Telefone, Telemovel, TipoC, Morada, Localidade, CodPostal FROM ((Terceiros INNER JOIN Contactos_Terceiro on Terceiros.CodCon = Contactos_Terceiro.CodCon ) INNER JOIN Morada_Terceiro on Terceiros.Numero = Morada_Terceiro.Numero ) where Nome like '%Joaquim%' limit 0, 15 "

Comment: Testa no banco direto para ver se a resposta esta correta ou se aparece algum erro

Comment: Banco direito??

Comment: Usando uma IDE ou linha de comando para rodar a consulta no banco sem o uso do PHP

Comment: Tentei seguir o conselho que deu, mas no entanto não apresentou erro nenhum

Comment: e o retorno tem quantos registros? está correto? simula a paginação alterando os valores na consulta

Comment: A realidade é que não retornou nada, não sei o que aconteceu